# IFrames Dual Scrollbar Issue

Tags: iframe

I am using an iframe right now.
This is not my first choice and I generally try to avoid them, but the problem is the client has different versions of their middleware on different boxes and is reluctant to upgrade one of them.
Anyway, now that I've made my excuses.  :)

I am trying to display a pretty sizable page and there is scrolling involved.  But for some reason, sometimes there are double scrollbars.  One on the page, the other in the iframe.

Does anyone have a workaround for this?  I would like to have just one scrollbar.

Comment: I think I figured it out, just eliminate all the margins in the enclosing file.

Comment: maybe you can answer your own question then accept it so anyone who has the same problem can see it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out, just eliminate all the margins in the enclosing file.